# How to determine which authentication method is used?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I was wondering: How can i determine which authentication method is in use?

For example I want to execute a code if my Authentication is based on FORMS authentication and not if it's WINDOWS Authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check what's on the web config using configuration manager

```
ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/authentication");
```

Comment: ... assuming the auth method is configured in IIS.

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve a string property called `AuthenticationType` on your user's identity object: `User.Identity.AuthenticationType`.

More documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.authenticationtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as I have several type of authentication methods enabled and working on my site. This will tell me which method the user used to authenticate.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have both the Windows Authentication and Forms Authentication both. For this you need to configure your IIS. Though it is very difficult to implement.
http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/
Check the above blog and the below discussion:-
[MVC3 mixed forms and Windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811273/mvc3-mixed-forms-and-windows-authentication) 
Hope this would help ypu anyway.
:)