# How to determine which Authentication method is used in a Visual Studio 2015 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, visual-studio-2015

I am working with a project I did not create from scratch, so I don't know what the "Big Creator" chose as Authentication method. Now I need to find out what it is. 
Yes I know, there was two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976866/how-to-determine-which-authentication-method-is-used), but I can not understand them.

The first one,

> You can check what's on the web config using configuration manager

In Visual Studio 2015, I found in "Build" Menu a "Configuration manager...", but I can not write code in it.

The second one,

> You can retrieve a string property called AuthenticationType on your user's identity object: User.Identity.AuthenticationType.

I did try to find where/what it is, without success.

I created two new projects: "NoAuthentication" and "IndividualUserAccounts" to compare the differences. At first, I was looking a little every where (App_Start, Controllers, Models, Web.config). I guess my project is not "No Authentication", because it has more stuff in those folders.

Problem 1: I do not know what/where to look for exactly.

Problem 2: What if the "Big Creator" selected "Organizational Accounts" or "Windows Authentication" ? How can I know for sure?

I need a clear way to find out : "Oh, this is a XYZ authentication".

I am sure I am missing something here, but what?

I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open your `web.config` file in your ASP.NET MVC project (you can find it at the root of the project) you will either see under:

`<system.web>`

A tag `<authentication mode= />`
Which can have a value of `Windows` for Windows Authentication.

Or a value of None or Forms (for No Authentication or Forms Authentication).

Alternatively you could see the following:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Combined with an `IdentityConfig` class under the `App_Start` folder then you are configured to use Individual User Accounts.

If you are seeing none of these you are under No Authentication.

Comment: I see it, but what is the logic behind :
          <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />  ?!?
Someone knows ?

Comment: @NathalieDesrosiers because this specific configuration option is now deprecated in newer versions of ASP.NET. See : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284380/is-formsauthentication-obsolete